# IOS: register for universal link when not owner of the domain

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, aasa

I try to create on iOS an application like https://f-droid.org/packages/app.fedilab.nitterizeme/ on android  to help a friend have the same feature (so it actually does not need to be an app per se)

i.e the user *explicitly* authorizes it to responds to twitter/youtube etc. links and redirect them to  non-tracking frontend or app (nitter.net etc. )

However my understanding is that Apple requires the app to put a special file on the domain to prove ownership.

Is there a way to workaround that if the user gives his explicit consent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no workaround for that

Comment: Would creating a "browser" work ?  (as firefox/chrome on ios have a  wildcard-ish on all http/https ?  )

Comment: I suspect you might have trouble with App Store review

Comment: true, would doing something like this work https://lukabratos.me/2020/05/08/removing-utm-parameters-with-apples-shortcuts/ ?   (I've edited my question to state it does not need to necessary be an app, as my main goal is just to help a non-dev friend )